# How does babel-standalone work?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

This is a noob question. Plz explain like I'm 5.

I understand the primary concept of babel-standalone. It transpiles jsx/ES6 files into ES5 when it's loaded. However, how does it affects the way my browser interprets a script? I mean, babel-standalone itself is nothing more than a script to be translated. It's not like a browser plugin or something.
When I look into the 'Sources' tab of Chrome developer tool, there still has a jsx/ES6 files not the transpiled ones. How could my browser begin to understand their syntax all of a sudden?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read their [docs](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone)? Remember: _always read the plaque_. --- If you have, what is your use-case?

Comment: I think what you are seeing in the sources tab is not the file acctually loaded but the pre-transpiled file linked via a sourcemap
see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps for more info about how sourcemaps work.

Comment: So is the main thing that confuses you *how* it works even if ES6/JSX has been loaded in its original form? Basically, babel loads that code as text, no evaluation is done during load so you can see "regular" JSX/ES6 in network tab or sources tab. Then it pulls it through its transpiler and sticks that transpiled string (which is now ES5) into browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Listen DOM Event.

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-standalone/src/index.js

```
// Listen for load event if we're in a browser and then kick off finding and
// running of scripts with "text/babel" type.
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window?.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDOMContentLoaded, false);
}
```

2. Get source script which is not raw javascript.

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-standalone/src/transformScriptTags.js

```
scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

3. Transform from the source to raw javascript.
4. Run by appending a script element with transformed content.

```
/**
 * Appends a script element at the end of the <head> with the content of code,
 * after transforming it.
 */
function run(transformFn, script) {
  const scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
  if (script.type) {
    scriptEl.setAttribute("type", script.type);
  }
  scriptEl.text = transformCode(transformFn, script);
  headEl.appendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

Comment: what is this  ? is this how babel works ?